# LINQ: Group items, then select Min and finally select Max

Tags: c#, linq

I have below list of items:

```
ID     Date
01200  11/11/2020
01200  11/11/2021             
02100  01/01/2019
02100  01/01/2029
```

I am trying to group items by ID, then for each group select the item which has the Max date, and finally select the item which has the Min date. Taken into account above set of items, the final result would be 11/11/2021.

So I have implemented two ways [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/X4ZeEq) to do the same thing. Option 1 is working but option 2 isn't.

Comment: Option 2 has a compiler error. Of course it will "not work" like that :) | Seems you tried to call `ToList<Foo>` without an argument, but expected is something like: `ToList<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)` - something with an argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

step-by-step:

```
// first get the groups:

var groups = items.GroupBy(i => i.ID);

// find the max date in each group
var maxDates = groups.Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(i => i.Date).First());

// now find the earliest max date
var minDate = maxDates.OrderBy(i => i.Date).First();
```

combined into one line:

```
var minDate = items.GroupBy(i => i.ID)
                   .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(i => i.Date).First())
                   .OrderBy(i => i.Date).First();
```

Comment: The final result minDate is not of type Foo so I cannot access to the whole object Foo, I mean, minDate.id and minDate.date.

Comment: "the final result would be 11/11/2021." that is what I went off of. I've updated to return the _item_ with that date, though.

Comment: Compiler says below error: "The name Max does not exist in the current context."

Comment: Great, now it works! You forgot one parenthesis after first first(). Please correct it.

Answer (score 0):

```
...
GroupBy(p => p.id, 
        p => p.date,
        (key, g) => new { id = key, date = g.Max() })
```

returns an `IEnumerable` of an anonymous type. You cannot convert anonymous type to type `Foo` via `.ToList<Foo>`.

You should rewrite you code to resolve compilation error as

```
var res2 = cv.GroupBy(
                         p => p.id, 
                         p => p.date,
                         (key, g) => new Foo{ id = key, date = g.Max()  //add here class name Foo
}).Aggregate((u,v) => u.date < v.date ? u: v);
```

**EDIT**: or if you not use `Dump()` to show result then you may use anonymous type in `GroupBy()` like:

```
var res2 = cv.GroupBy(
                         p => p.id, 
                         p => p.date,
                         (key, g) => new { id = key, date = g.Max() }).Aggregate((u,v) => u.date < v.date ? u: v);
```

Also you may use @D Stanley idea to find `Foo` object like:

```
var minDate = cv.GroupBy(i => i.id,
                         p => p.date,
                         (key, g) => new Foo() { id = key, date = g.Max() }).OrderBy(e=>e.date).First();
```

Comment: Solution proposed by @D Stanley does not return an object of type Foo. Your solution does but what if object Foo has a lot of public fields? let's say Foo,date1, ..., Foo.dateN. I want to avoid to build an object Foo specifying all the fields explicitly, I want to return the whole object Foo without needing to specifying all the fields manually.

Comment: @user1624552 please read you question. You don't ask how resolve your problem in general case, you ask how correct your second way. If you want find decision for your problem in general case, then create new question. And I, if find this question, with pleasure give you answer.